# XAML Designer "cannot find type" when converters are in UserControl.Resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, designer, cider

I have a WPF UserControl with binding converters referenced like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl" x:Name="MyControl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TheMainNamespaceOfThisAssembly">

    <UserControl.Resources>
      <local:ConfidenceColorConverter x:Key="ConfidenceColorConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

I then use the binding converter later.  I see the user control in my design window.  Then I compile, then place this user control in my main window.  I run it and it works.  However, I still would like to use the designer on the main window, which breaks with:

> Could not create an instance of type 'MyControl'.

So I learned [how to debug the designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514636.aspx); when I do, I get an XamlParseException:

> Cannot find type 'TheMainNamespaceOfThisAssembly.ConfidenceColorConverter'. The assembly used when compiling might be different than that used when loading and the type is missing.  Error in markup file...

If remove the references to the converters, my user control displays well in the designer on the main window.  **Any ideas how to fix my references to the converters so that they won't break the designer?**

Couldn't understand if the article [Troubleshooting WPF Designer Load Failures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546934.aspx#ResourcesatDesignTime) applies or not.

Comment: I couldn't get any sort of error due to similar class name and key, so I deleted my answer. I have to ask the obvious: You do have a class called `ConfidenceColorConverter` in the assembly, right? Is it public?

Comment: Yes; ConfidenceColorConverter, MyControl, and MainWindow are all in the same project with project namespace TheMainNamespaceOfThisAssembly.

Comment: Please try to reproduce this on a clean project. This *should not* fail, so it is important to reproduce it without any odd side-effects from the project.

Comment: OK, that works.  Where can I look for causes of side effects?

Comment: Does it not compile or only on display in designer?
What platforms are defined for the assembly?

Comment: Yes, only the designer gives me the problem.  My active platform is "Any CPU"--can't imagine that would affect anything?

Comment: Try cleaning the solution, check Configuration Manager for consistency of settings for all projects in the solution. Try renaming converter classes/keys - I've seen odd clashes when referencing the same ResourceDictionary more than once.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with others, the VS2008 designer has numerous problems that prevent its use in many situations.  We gave up.

Update: It seems like some, especially Joel Cochran, are using the Expression Blend design view with more success, as long as you obey his [four principles of MVVM](http://practicalmvvm.com/Manifesto/) in XAML development.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to reproduce the problem on a clean new project rather than editing your existing one? You cannot have

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl" x:Name="MyControl"...
```

as you would need to add a namespace to "x:class" and change "x:Name" value to be different from class name. The designer works fine when I create a clean project as you describe and fix this sort of errors. You might be omitting some details from the question you think are unimportant, but those details can make all the difference.

Comment: Try using a naming convention in which private fields and XAML keys are camelCase and classes and types are PascalCase.

Comment: I tried changing the x:name to "thisControl" while keeping MyControl as the class name. I tried creating a new project with a converter as a resource used on a binding inside a user control, and the user control used in a Window. That indeed works as Stanislav says. 

I then simplified my Window and user control in the original project to nothing but the namespaces and XAML needed (matching the near-empty test project), and I still get the error. I'm about to rip out the code-behind of the user control down to a bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I'd be happy to post omitted details if I knew what they could be.

Comment: Well, I cannot figure it out.  The test project works, but the actual project doesn't.  Don't know what other differences to try changing.